# how can i create a function gentimes() to create nreps of a point(w1,w2)

Tags: r, arrays, function

`x1,x2`: times for two customers to arrive  which follows an Exponential(0.2)

`y1,y2`: times to serve two customers  which follows an Exponential(0.25)

`w1,w1`: the times in minutes that each customer spends either waiting to be served or being served.

I want to write a [function](/questions/tagged/function) `gentimes()` for `nreps` that compute (x1,x2),(y1,y2) then computes (w1,w2)
and produces an output nreps*2 [array](/questions/tagged/array).

**Does w1 and w2 follow an exponential of 0.45?** I know that if `w1=y1` then `w2>y2`

here's my attempt:

```
    gentimes=function(nreps)
      {

        x1=rexp(nreps,0.2)
        x2=rexp(nreps,0.2)
        y1=rexp(nreps,0.25)
        y2=rexp(nreps,0.25)
        w1=rexp(nreps,0.45)
        w2=rexp(nreps,0.45)
if(w1==y1)
{
pmax(w1,y2)
}
randomw1w2=array(0,c(2,nreps))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
genTimes = function(nreps){
  x  = matrix(rexp(2 * nreps, rate = 0.2), nc = 2)
  y  = matrix(rexp(2 * nreps, rate = 0.25), nc  = 2)

  w = x + y

  return(w)
}
```